# retrieving data from service to activity OnResume()

Tags: c#, android, service, xamarin.android, xamarin

I've been stuck on a problem for a while now. My activity starts and sends data (DT start, DT finish, Char action) to my service using `ServiceName.PutExtra(name,value)` in activity `OnPause()`, but It also need to read new values for the same.

The activity uses the GPS to record when the device is moving and when not, and start and finishtime of these.

When I go back to my activity `OnResume()` needs to read in what the service currently records, continue this recording and stop the service.

I have read a lot about binding the service, but can not get this to work using simple code samples with the explanations ( sourced @ Xamarin site, android developers site, stackoverflow)

Can someone show me a code where the binding is clearly stated between service-activity, and how to get data from the service into activity OnResume()??

I work with Xamarin and C#, but I can adapt from java code if needed

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it for a long time (because I'm using LocalBroadcasts for this purpose now) so I can missed something, but in general it would be something like that (in java):

in Activity:

```
/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder service) {
    LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
    mStateChecker = binder.getService();
    mBound = true;

    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent2); 
}


public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
     mBound = false;

     Intent intent2 = getIntent();
     finish();
     startActivity(intent2);

    }   
};




 //start the service & bind to it
    startService(new Intent(this, StateChecker.class));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StateChecker.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

in Service:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return mBinder;
}

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    StateChecker getService() {    //  StateChecker is the name of this class
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return StateChecker.this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, but could not get it to work right for me.... looking into just binding it without data exchange (keep service alive while activity is going as well) and using broadcasts to communicate the data.